# Arabic OCR in .Net

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, arabic

I used Tesseract and trained it with complete word as character, How chinese OCR are doing. But this kills me to make my own fonts and its a time consuming and slow process. This approach is good for some scenario but I wanted to trained tesseract based on arabic characters.

Or Suggest me which can help me developed my own arabic ocr with or without Tesseract.

I have researched on OpenCV but it didnt go well.

I will highly appreicate your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

Tesseract has pre-trained files for a lot of languages, [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-3.02.ara.tar.gz&can=2&q=) is the Arabic one.

Comment: I was using Tesseract, I trained tesseract with default arabic characters and its accurate rate is very less. you need to create your own fonts file and then based on that you will train tesseract to work. But this way, I will always be creating new font and will be dependent on it.

It is possible to create fonts based on character we found from any scanned document?

Comment: I think you need to first find which font was used to create the document, since training in Tesseract needs you to digitally generate files with that font. You can read about training [link](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3) here

Comment: I have already read this article thanks for sharing. But I do not want to be dependent on the fonts.

Comment: Is there any other library available other than Tesseract for Arabic OCR.

Comment: I am trying to use Tesseract to train on arabic characters. But success rate is only 60%.

Comment: I am afraid I have never experimented with anything more powerful than Tesseract. You can check out some custom implementation using some powerful machine learning techniques, but first I would try out training with multiple fonts with Tesseract itself, and some preprocessing to ensure that Tesseract gets the desired inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but for whoever is looking for the same, now tesseract 4 comes with pre-trained Arabic data alongside many other languages which can be found [here](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best)

And here is a demo of [Arabic OCR](https://devtools360.com/en/ocr/ara) based on tesseract 4, you can see how accurate it becomes now.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Is it https://devtools360.com/en/ocr/ara open source?

Comment: @AsjalRana The tools itself no, but the engine it is using is open source, you can find it here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract